# Error R10 (Boot timeout) when running firebase node.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have node.js code similar to this one:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var request = require('request');

var API_KEY = "..."; // Your Firebase Cloud Server API key

firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: ".json",
  databaseURL: "https://.firebaseio.com/"
});
ref = firebase.database().ref();

function listenForNotificationRequests() {
  var requests = ref.child('notificationRequests');
  ref.on('child_added', function(requestSnapshot) {
    var request = requestSnapshot.val();
    sendNotificationToUser(
      request.username, 
      request.message,
      function() {
        request.ref().remove();
      }
    );
  }, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
};

function sendNotificationToUser(username, message, onSuccess) {
  request({
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' :' application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key='+API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      notification: {
        title: message
      },
      to : '/topics/user_'+username
    })
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) { console.error(error); }
    else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
      console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage); 
    }
    else {
      onSuccess();
    }
  });
}

// start listening
listenForNotificationRequests();
```

My question is how to run it on heroku? When I try it is giving me **Error R10 (Boot timeout)** -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch. Procfile is like this:

```
worker: node server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my guess:**

You probably have something similar to this in your code (just not posted):

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(server.js);
server.listen(5000);
```

Well, that `server.listen(5000);` is forcing the app to connect to port 5000 and listen.

***Heroku doesn't work that way.*** It will automatically assign a port to your `env` and use that. So you need to tell your app "Hey, use the `env` port, or use 5000 as a backup". You can do this like this:

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Again, this is just a guess considering you didn't post your code that refers to the port number. My example might differ from yours, but it's the same general concept.

Comment: My code does not use ports as well. Otherwise I would have changed it, I will try your suggestion and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by this:

```
//add this in the begining

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

//this at the end

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  listenForNotificationRequests();
});
```

Comment: I knew that was the problem, but this is the code people should use if they run into that.